# Creating a PDF image in iText

Tags: itext

I'm trying to add an image that I have on the filesystem as a pdf into a pdf that I'm creating on the fly.

I tried to use the Image class, but it seems that it does not work with PDFs (only JPEG, PNG or GIF).  How can I create an element from an existing PDF, so that I can place it in my new PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) and read all about the class `PdfImportedPage`.

In the most basic example, you'd create a `PdfReader` instance and import the page into the `PdfWriter` instance, from which point on you can use the `PdfImportedPage` instance, either directly, or wrapped inside an `Image` object:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(existingPdf);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
Image img = Image.getInstance(page);
reader.close();
```